# Issue in using form group inside form array in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am dynamically adding form groups inside a formArray on button click using following code

Typescript:

```
 const control= this.fb.group({
    'visitor_name'  : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern(/^[A-Za-z ]+$/)])],
    'visitor_email' : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$')])],
    'visitor_phone' : ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.pattern('^[0-9]{7,}$')])]
  })

  const creds = this.visitorForm.controls.visitors as FormArray;

  creds.push(control)
```

And accessing in the following way from my html

HTML:

```
    <div formArrayName="visitors"  >
      <div class="row item" *ngFor="let item of visitorForm.controls.visitors.controls let i = index " [formGroup] = "getFormGroup(i)">
      <div class="text-item">
        <label for="visitor_name">Visitor {{i+1}} Name<span>*</span></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="visitor_name" maxlength="50">
      </div>
      </div>
   <div>
```

I am assigning my form group from my typescript by using the function

Typescript:

```
getFormGroup(i){
return (<FormArray>this.visitorForm.controls.visitors).controls[i]
```

}

my Issue is that in the textbox the cursor is getting removed on pressing on character and i have to click textbox again to type further

Comment: I don't see a problem with your code. Maybe there's something else that you don't show here that causes the problem? Can you provide more of the component? And which version of angular do you use?

Comment: I am using angular 9. I will first seperate this code to another component to confirm if my code is correct and will reply to u accordingly

Comment: sorry for late reply, i seperated out this much code to different project but it is giving me the same error